# Is there any way to customize margin boxes contents on Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to customize print (margin boxes) on Chrome version 45.0.2454.85 m.

I found lot of questions about this, and accepteded answers as well, but non of those worked for me.

It seem that this:

```
@media print {
    @page { margin: 0px; }
}
```

works as supposed to be, and hides margin boxes. But what I'd like to do is just customize margin boxes. When I try to do this like in [Page-Margin Boxes at www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-boxes)

```
@media print {
    @page {
        @top-center {
               content: "Custom center text";
        }
    }
}
```

no effect to boxes at all.

Comment: I guess there is no way.. as i have also tried but not able to find any solution. Then i worked on print media css to fix things.

Comment: None of the major browsers support the page-margin boxes yet. Only margins and size. Ref - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29#Grammar_and_rules